# How to convert JSON string to array?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php

I need to get the values of a custom field list type 
with sql. I extract the fieldparams value using

```
SELECT  fieldparams,id  FROM #__fields where context='com_content.article' and state=1
```

And i get a string like this

```
{"multiple":"0","options":{
"options0":{"name":"name1","value":"value1"},
"options1":{"name":"name2","value":"value2"}}}
```

How do I convert this string into an array?

Comment: This question belongs to stackoverflow, because you are asking about converting JSON strings to PHP arrays, which is not primarily a Joomla question.

Answer (score 5):

```
$your_array = json_decode($json_data, true);
```

More about the decode options:
http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php

More about JSON: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php

Comment: This is backwards, Dennis.

Comment: You can’t echo an array, Dennis.

Comment: Thank you for giving a helping hand by pointing out things via comments, instead of just editing that obvious mistake, James.

Comment: My pleasure. ;)